# How can I show the user email ID using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmail

I am a beginner and I want to make a program that can tell me that with which email account I am logged in using javascript.... Just as it is in the google homepage

Comment: which account you are logged in to where? your site?

Comment: I want  to make it in a webpage using javascript

Comment: is this your website